# 3D viewport size

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, size, viewport

I want to make a image of my viewport but the only way I know is the following

```
Image myImage = new Image();
RenderTargetBitmap bmp;
bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)this.Width, (int)this.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(myViewPort);

myImage.Source = bmp;
myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
```

I am using the windows actual size and height to be sure that the bmp get "big enough" even if the viewport takes up a smaller part of the window

The viewport resist in a grid like this

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="ViewPortGrid" Background="SteelBlue" >
    <Viewport3D Name="myViewPort" >
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

I can not use ViewPortGrid.Widht/Height or myViewPort.Widht/Height when creating the bmp becosue these are NaN.

Are there better ways of creating an image of the viewport ?

Is there a way of getting the true size of the viewport so the creating of the RenderTargetBitmap is equal to the size of the viewport (using the window size makes the image  much bigger than needed) ?

/Stefan

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at Eric Sink's series on WPF 3D - in particular this post: http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/3_Bitmap.html.

Comment: I have been looking there but it does not say where he gets the height and weight form in the first place. Note that my viewport is not fixed in size, the user can drag in the edges of the window and by that change the size of the viewport which in turn menas that Í have to determinate the size of the viewport in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .ActualWidth and .ActualHeight properties.

This has to do with the way things are rendered and handled in WPF, which is completely different from WinForms.

See:

http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/03/14/Why-is-the-WidthHeight-Property-for-many-Elements-e28098NaNe28099-in-WPF.aspx